# PageSpeed Insights optimize .jpg with jpegoptim lossy ideal %?

Tags: jpeg, pagespeed, image-compression, jpegoptim, lossy-compression

I am trying to remove **'Optimize images'** warning from Google PageSpeed Insights.
Validator says I can do about **40 - 50% image reduction** for each jpg on my website. So I installed jpegoptim on Ubuntu and firstly try lossless optimization. It did about 7% reduction, so when I uploaded images on website and run validation, warning 'Optimize images' still occurs.

So I tried to go on lossy optimization of 90% quality. It save about 16% image reduction, but it's still not enough. And when i go to 50% quality to get on 40 -50% image reduction, images are bad quality.

I tried to use https://compressor.io with lossy optimization and i got really fine reduction. I looked on **about section** and they use jpegoptim for .jpg so where can be problem? I have to implement jpegoptim to my app and i can't run every single jpg with compressor.io.

I want to remove this Pagespeed warning, because it looks like important. But i don't have to use bad quality images on website. Do you have any experiences with this? 
Thank you.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Well I am using jpegoptim with 85% compression. It's enough for Google Pagespeed and quality of images is still good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/).  In their results they will give you a compressed image.

I use http://compressjpeg.com/

Neither will reduce the quality of the images.